# WCF client unit test/integration test

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wcf-client

I generated a proxy client to a SOAP web service. I would like to test the request envelop without actually calling the service at the other end (actual endpoint)
for now, i wrap my tests in try/catch block as It will timeout. 
is they a way fake the endpoint as I'm only testing the request body?

Answer (score 1):

Use *New MockService* option from within [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Here are detailed steps:

1. Create a new SoapUI project
2. As a Initial WSDL provide url of you local service (with ?wsdl added) or WSDL of external service
3. Right click generated endpoint and select *Generate MockService* option. Select appropriate path and port.
4. You can edit default response that will be used.

Comment: I can do that. but I prefer to programmatically fake the endpoint and perform my tests on the generated SOAP request envelop.

Comment: Then I would self host dummy WCF service implementing this contract.