# how to programmatically change a method

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a test application to test an Operation Contract in the a service

Test client:

here is how I am making a call from my test to get the returned bool value

```
   bool operateResult =  TestContext.ServiceOperator.Operate(ref Inputmessage);
```

Service:

The operate method above calls another method

```
      bool  Operate(){
        OperatorProcess(msg, interface);
      }

        private bool OperatorProcess(ref Message MessageData, string SendInterface)
        {
        parse(message);
        validate(message);
        Transfer(message);
        }
```

From my test my goal is to test the operator method but in the process operator I don't want to 
            reach the Transfer(message) I want it to exit right after validate and get the result.

How can I programmatically modify it from my test application? Thanks

Note : the transfer method  send the parsed and validated method to another service and I want to stop it from sending my request to that service.

Comment: Are you able to modify OperatorProcess?

Comment: no i am not ...  I can modify it only from the test client not the service

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest the answer below but if you can't modify it I'm not sure there's much you can do.

Comment: actually what that transfer method does is send the parsed and validated method to another service and I want to stop it from sending my request to that service

Comment: What do you mean by that you can't modify `OperatorProcess` method? Is it a third-party code or you just want to modify it?

Comment: If you really can't modify it, do not get rid of external service call but use mock service as I described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148345/wcf-client-unit-test-integration-test)

Comment: @Konrad I updated my question with more inforation

Comment: the service code is not  a 3rd party code.

Comment: @HXD so I still not understand why you can't modify `OperationProcess`. Nevertheless I suggest you to mock this external service (but it won't be a clean unit test then) or use `Dependency Injection` and mock Transfer behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try extending the class that contains the OperationProcess function and overriding the function then calling your overridden function that only does the few parts you care about... You can keep the parts in your function that you care about and only the functionality you need to test for.

[C# examples on how to override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks this makes a lot sense to me ... I will try it later today and will let you know the result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a global boolean variable test then set it to true during testing and set it to false during production, then you method will look similar to

```
private bool OperatorProcess(ref Message MessageData, string SendInterface)
{
    parse(message);
    validate(message);
    if(!TEST)  Transfer(message);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a global variable, then you can just add a parameter to the method signature

```
private bool OperatorProcess(ref Message MessageData, string SendInterface, bool performTransfer)
{
    parse(message);
    validate(message);
    if(performTransfer)  Transfer(message);
}
```

Comment: the OperatorProcess method is not exposed for the client its a method that the operator method used internally.